# Is there a way to constrain protobuf numeric fields to certain range?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

Let's say I have a protobuf message like

```
message Person {
   uint32 age = 1;
}
```

Is there a way to constraint field `age` to certain range? Like `[0; 120]`. For now I just have these checks programmatically

```
if p.Age < 0 || p.Age > 120 {
    return err
}
```

but it's tedious to write the same error messages again and again (in reality I have a much bigger mesage). Would be great also to have the same constraint validation across all the projects that use this protobuf definition - right now we need to informally coordinate it among developers.

Comment: There is nothing built-in, but there are proto validators such as [this one](https://github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators). This falls under the category of library recommendations, so off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

```
message Person {
   uint32 age = 1; [
       (buf.validate.field).uint32.gt = 0,
       (buf.validate.field).uint32.lt = 120,
   ];
}
```

You will need to `import "buf/validate/validate.proto"`

Please refer https://github.com/bufbuild/protovalidate/blob/b0c0e8aaf81210677dd7e4d8b589bcf4ba110a04/proto/protovalidate/buf/validate/validate.proto#L960 for more details